# Apex Report: "query column is invalid, use column alias"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am receiving an error stating:

> query column #4 (DECODE(A.SUBMISSION_TYPE,'D','DIGITALSUBMISSION','S','SUBMISSIONLOG','M','MAIL')) is invalid, use column alias

and I don't know how to fix it.

```
select a.phase,a.st_code||' - '||b.state_name,
a.submission_received_dt,
DECODE (a.submission_type,'D','Digital Submission','S','Submission Log', 'M', 'Mail'),
a.no_change_dt
from pcspro.sdrp15_return a, pcspro.sdrp15_states_ready b 
where a.phase = b.phase and a.st_code = b.state;
```

Comment: Sorry I need to edit it again, but I did that and im still receiving the error.

Comment: try using a alias for `decode` like : `DECODE (a.submission_type,'D','Digital Submission','S','Submission Log', 'M', 'Mail') as somecol`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a report in Apex, it uses the query to determine what the columns are. SQL*Plus automatically generates column names for unaliased expressions but Apex does not - you must supply them yourself, e.g.

```
a.st_code||' - '||b.state_name AS mycolname

DECODE(...) AS anothercolname
```